# How to query and update all documents array

Tags: mongoose

I have one question about mongoose:

I have a collection of "users"  in "mongodb" and they all have "friends" array, I need to push new data to the "friends" array of specific users, is there a way to do it with a single query?

This is the schema:

```javascript
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    pictureUrl : String,
    devices : [String],
    friends : [String]
});
mongoose.model('user',userSchema);
```

I want to do something like this

```javascript
friends = [7823g87yh87y,ou327ujjghd9,py98hd98y23yh];
newUser["_id"] = ObjectId(236487g872he87y78);

user.update(
    {"_id": friends}, 
    {$push: {"friends": newUser["_id"]}},
    function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the schema for users and some example data?

Comment: i want to get all user "friends" documents,update "friends" array and save,thanks for response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) to match `_id` against an array of values, and the `{multi: true}` option to apply the update to all matching docs instead of just the first:

```javascript
user.update(
    {"_id": {$in: friends}}, 
    {$push: {"friends": newUser["_id"]}},
    {multi: true},
    function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
    });
```